# Capture android TV remote keycode

Tags: keyevent, android-tv

My android app has a function to detect all the keycodes for TV remote.

I tried **onKeyDown(up)** API to detect when the user press the TV remote and override **dispatchKeyEvent** method too. It works except some keys : **mute, volume, home, back**. how can I detect those keys?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The system has the privilege to control those keys, so I have to find some source code to use.

I final resolved this problem. In general, AOSP dispose a led service (led controller):

```
  public LedService() {
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        this.handlePowerStateChanged(0);
        return new LedService.LedServiceWrapper();
    }

    public void handlePowerStateChanged(int state) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "handlePowerStateChanged: " + state);
        }

    }

    public void handleKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleKeyEvent: " + event);
        }

    }
```

This class use HAL to go down the level and communicate directly with system. I extend this class in my own class and use handleKeyEvent method.

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

Check the [`KeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#summary) constants, and by the help of the following SO references.

- [Detect home button press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android)
- [Check if back key was pressed in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182703/check-if-back-key-was-pressed-in-android)
- [Android: How to get app to remember if mute button has been pressed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849253/android-how-to-get-app-to-remember-if-mute-button-has-been-pressed-or-not)
- [Android - Volume Buttons used in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874743/android-volume-buttons-used-in-my-application)