# Detect Mute|UnMute on Android TV

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer, android-tv

I made Media Android TV application by using [SimpleExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer),

It can play some musics, some videos,

I want to track user when Mute|UnNute by using remote to trigger.

Therefore, I want to detect Mute|UnMute mode on current TV devices.

I research many [pages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager), still not find out that,

Hope someone can help me the way,

Thank you,

p/s : These codes did not detect for Android TV

```
You can use AudioManager to check volume is mute or not mute.

AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch( audio.getRingerMode() ){
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
break;
}
```

Comment: Have you check [this SO post (Android: How to get app to remember if mute button has been pressed or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849253/android-how-to-get-app-to-remember-if-mute-button-has-been-pressed-or-not)?

Comment: I just find the way in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I only get only this way to detect Mute|UnMute of Android system.

```
public static boolean isSoundOn(Context context) {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    /*
     * It can detect
     *   - from Android 6.0 : Check Stream Music
     * */
    boolean isSoundOn = false;
    if (NlbUtil.isAndroidMarshmallow()) {
        // from Android 6.0 : Stream Music
        isSoundOn = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) != 0;   // If no sound system, return true
        // isSoundOn = !am.isStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    return isSoundOn;
}
```